# LINQ datasource and BindingNavigator update deosn't work

Tags: winforms, linq, bindingsource

I'm trying to set a LINQ query as the DataSource of a BindingNavigator control.

In the form's variables I added a data context:

`Private c

tx As New myDataManagerDataContext`

The following code allows me to display and navigate through the results:

```
Dim clubList = From c In ctx.clubs _
                   Select c

BindingNavigator1.BindingSource.DataSource = clubList
```

Each record is displayed nicely so far.
In the Winform, all textboxes are duly binded to the datasource but my problem is:

I added a Save ToolboxButton with: ctx.SubmitChanges()

But it doesn't process any update!

Question: Do I HAVE to write a complete Insert/ Update Linq procedure in the Save button?

Like:

`Dim newClub as new DataContext.Club 
newClub.Name = NameTextBox.Text
newClub.Address.... Etc.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to call EndEdit on binding source just before save operation to happen.

Comment: I try, but it doesn't do any more effect :-(